# trying to return value from dict.items() is not working

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, return

There is a problem is have to solve here it is

You are given a string of numbers between 0-9. Find the average of these numbers and return it as a floored whole number (ie: no decimal places) written out as a string. Eg:

"zero nine five two" -> "four"

here is my code

```
from math import floor

 x = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight','nine']


def average_string(s):
    s = s.split(' ')
    dnumber = {k: i for i, k in enumerate(x)}
    converter = [l for n, l in dnumber.items() for i in s if n == i]
    floorN = floor(sum(converter) - len(converter))

    for i,k in dnumber.items(): 
          if k == floorN:
             return i #<--is this the problem?

print(average_string("zero nine five two"))
```

why is it returning None is there another way compare and return a value from a dict.items()

Comment: if `k` is never equal to `floorN` then the function returns `None`. You should return something in that case (at the end of the for loop)

Comment: also, using a dictionary like this is suspicious.

Comment: how did i get this off track smh

Comment: your average formula is wrong: use `floor(sum(converter) / len(converter))`

Comment: thank you i totally forgot thats when you look at a formula very quickly without paying attention   but why do you say using a dictionary like this is very suspicious i am interested in knowing another way @Jean-FrançoisFabre

Comment: see the last part of my answer for an efficient implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result should be "four". But your average formula is wrong: you have to sum then *divide* not subtract.

So when you're looping (what a strange idea?) in the dictionary, you don't find the value, so you reach the end of the function and python returns `None` in that case.

So fix the formula, then instead of flooring, convert back to index using *integer division* so everything is kept as integers, and use `x` to convert to letter-as-string:

```
def average_string(s):
    s = s.split(' ')
    dnumber = {k:i for i, k in enumerate(x)}
    converter = [l for n, l in dnumber.items() for i in s if n == i]
    floorN = sum(converter) // len(converter)

    return x[floorN-1]
```

as an aside, you could put the `dnumber` computation out of the function, since it doesn't depend on the passed parameters (faster if there are many calls), also you don't really use the dictionary as efficiently as it should be. A clear rewrite would be:

```
x = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight','nine']
dnumber = {k:i for i, k in enumerate(x)}

def average_string(s):
    converter = [dnumber[w] for w in s.split()]
    floorN = int(sum(converter) / len(converter))
    return x[floorN]
```

now that I've put `zero` in the dictionary, I'm able to convert from letter to digit and back, without any loop, to benefit from fast dict/list lookup.

Answer (score 0):

To reduce the number of `foo-loops` to be used, including `sum` you can do:

```
def average_string(s):
    x = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight','nine']
    total = 0
    for i,j in enumerate(x):
        if j in s:
            total += i+1
    return total//len(s.split())
```

If you include the `zero` in the list, then your order becomes `0(n)` by doing the following:

```
def average_string(s):
    x = ['zero','one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight','nine']
    total = 0
    count = 0
    for i,j in enumerate(x):
        if j in s:
            total += i
            count += 1
    return total//count
```